# strcmp always producing the same result

Tags: c, strcmp

I have a LinkedList implementation which holds structs which contain words and a few other pieces of information. In the LinkedList I have a function which checks to see if a word is
already contained in one of the structs in the list. Problem is, this returns 0 every single time. Any idea why this is?

This compiles completely fine and every single aspect of this function works besides the `if(strcmp(ll->value->word, word))` statement.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add in the !

```
int llContains(LinkedList* ll, char* word){

    LinkedList* nn= ll;
    if(nn != NULL){
       for(int i=0; nn != NULL; i++){
           if(!strcmp(ll->value->word, word)){
               return i;
           }
           nn = nn->next;
       }
    } else {
       return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You understand that `strcmp` returns 0 for matching strings?

Comment: Sorry everybody, forgot to put in the `!`. The problem was the `else`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has undefined behaviour as there is a path through the function that does not have an explicit `return`: if the `return` within the `for` is not executed.

Note that `strcmp()` returns `0` when strings equal so the `if` within the `for` will be "true" if the strings do not match. This means if the first entry in the list does not equal then `0` will be returned.

Change to:

```
int llContains(LinkedList* ll, char* word){

    LinkedList* nn= ll;
    if(nn != NULL){
       for(int i=0; nn != NULL; i++){
           if(strcmp(ll->value->word, word) == 0){
               return i;
           }
           nn = nn->next;
       }
    }

    /* ALWAYS return a value. */
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: True ... the else should NOT be there

Comment: Thank you! That was it. The `else` seemed like a very good idea at the time, but obviously wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Add some debug info before "return i"

```
int llContains(LinkedList* ll, char* word){

LinkedList* nn= ll;
if(nn != NULL){
   for(int i=0; nn != NULL; i++){
       if(strcmp(ll->value->word, word)){
           printf("Linked->word : %s, word : %s\n",ll->value->word, word);
           return i;
       }
       nn = nn->next;
   }
} else {
   return -1;
}
```

}

Try this, and let's see what you have